# How to remove C-style comments from code

Tags: javascript, java, c++, regex, comments

I just read a new question here on SO asking basically the same thing as mine does in the title. That got me thinking - and searching the web (most hits pointed to SO, of course ;). So I thought -

**There should be a simple regex capable of removing C-style comments from any code.**

Yes, there are answers to this question/statement on SO, but the ones I found, the're all incomplete and/or overly complex.

So I started experimenting, and came up with one that works on all types of code **I** can imagine:

```
(?:\/\/(?:\\\n|[^\n])*\n)|(?:\/\*(?:\n|\r|.)*?\*\/)|(("|')(?:\\\\|\\\2|\\\n|[^\2])*?\2)
```

The first alternative checks for *double slash* `//` comments. The second for *ordinary* ones `/* comment */`. The third one is what I had trouble finding other regex'es dealing with the same task handling - **strings containing character sequences that outside the string, would be considered comments**.

What this part does is to capture any strings in capture group one, matching the quote sign in capture group two, to quoted ones, up to the end of the string.

Capture group one should be kept in the replace, everything discarded (replaced for `""`) leaving un-commented code :).

[Here's a C example at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/qY4xD3/2)

OK... So that's not a question. It's an answer you think...

Yes, you're right. So... on to the question.

**Have I missed any type of code that this regex would miss?**

It handles

multi line comments

```
/*
    an easy one
*/
```

"end of line" comments

```
// Remove this
```

comments in strings

```
char array[] = "Following isn't a comment // because it's in a string /* this neither */";
```

which leads to - strings with escaped quotes

```
    char array[] = "Handle /* comments */ - // - in strings with \" escaped quotes";
```

and strings with escaped escapes

```
    char array[] = "Handle strings with **not** escaped quotes\\"; // <-EOS
```

javscript single quoted string

```
var myStr = 'Should also ignore enclosed // comments /* like these */ ';
```

line continuation

```
// This is a single line comment \
continuing on the next row (warns, but works in my C++ flavor)
```

So, **can you think of any code cases messing this up?** If you come up with any I'll try to complete the RE and hopefully it'll end up *complete* ;)

Regards.

PS. I know... Writing this it says in the right pane, under *How to Ask*: *We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.* This question might violate that :S but I can't resist.

In fact, it may even turn out to be an answer, instead of a question, to some people. (Too cocky? ;)

Comment: There are a couple of issues: `(?:\n|\r|.)*?` should be replaced with something like `[\s\S]*?` (and the best way is to unroll it with unroll-the-loop technique) and `[^\2]` matches any characters but `\2` (not a backreferences!)

Comment: Character constant made up of more than one character:  `int a = '//';`

Comment: You do not seem to be handling trigraphs :)

Comment: C++11's raw string literal: `R"x("/**/)x"`

Comment: Not sure but have you checked `/*<CR> //*/`

Comment: @chux OK, nice one. Been programming C-based languages for 30 years and din't know you could do that :D

Comment: @Biffen Good, will check that. Same for C#'s `@" not quoted quote \"`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon That one is handled.

Comment: You should have added some more languages. How about Pascal, Cobol or Brainfuck?

Comment: I strongly disagree with the assertion that "There should be a simple regex capable of removing C-style comments from any code."  I don't see why one would presume so.   Moreover, the candidate regex does not support the proposition, and as has been observed, it even then does not cover all the cases.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That was what the question was - have I missed any cases.

Comment: @EOF, you are right.  Dunno how I made that slip.  Previous comment deleted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know where the border ;) between complex and simple REs go, but IMO this is still pretty simple. And I *feel* that you have a problem with accepting the notion... But I don't ;) If you could help me instead and point me to a case that isn't handled - or rather, to support your statement - is impossible to handle in a relatively simple RE?

Comment: A parsing problem like this would require a proper parser don't you think?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Please, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. Any suggestions on **why this wouldn't work**?

Comment: Not that it really matters six years later, but to expand on what @JohnBollinger was saying: to my mind, claiming that "There should be a simple regex capable of removing C-style comments from any code" is the logical equivalent of saying "It should be possible to drive screws using a hammer".  And, yes, it's true, you *can* drive screws with a hammer, just as you *can* remove C comments using a regex.  But it's not the best tool for the job, and you're likely to make a mess of it.  But on the other hand... if you enjoy hacky challenges, it may be a fine one of those! :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for your thoughts (not that it really matters two years later (almost exactly :)). If you only had a hammer and no screwdriver - would you give up? What I'm getting at is that at several occasions have I come across situation where the only way I can solve a problem, is by using regex. E.g. when a third party tools let's you filter stuff (in my case logs) using regex.
I use Notepad++ a lot, and then I've actually used this regex lots of times to review code, when the comments are irrelevant (in my cases in a language I don't understand).

Comment: And also @SteveSummit, I've never seen the "screwdriver" doing this. If you could recommend such a tool it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @SamWhan When it comes to most full-blown computer languages like C, the right and only tool for parsing them is a full-blown compiler, or at least, the lexical analyzer that makes up the first stage of that full-blown compiler.  Anything else is probably going to miss some cases.

Comment: If you don't want to write a full-blown compiler or lexical analyzer just to separate comments, you can ask the folks who wrote your compiler if they would consider adding a compiler option, or writing a separate but related tool, to do it.  (They might decline -- indeed I'm not aware of such an option in any compiler I've used -- but IMO it's a reasonable request.)

Comment: So, in the end, your point about "the only way I can solve a problem, is by using regex" is well taken.  (That is, in an emergency, if you don't have the screwdriver, you might have to settle for an imperfect job done with the hammer.)

Comment: Actually, though, writing a comment-stripping tool — based on a full-blown lexical analyzer — needn't be a big or hard project.  Lexical analyzers can be quite easy to write, especially if you use a tool like [`lex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) or [`flex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) to help you.  (That is, `lex` is the "screwdriver" here — in fact I think it was once described as the "Swiss Army knife" of Unix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've considered the comments (so far) and changed the regex to:

```
(?:\/\/(?:\\\n|[^\n])*\n)|(?:\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)|((?:R"([^(\\\s]{0,16})\([^)]*\)\2")|(?:@"[^"]*?")|(?:"(?:\?\?'|\\\\|\\"|\\\n|[^"])*?")|(?:'(?:\\\\|\\'|\\\n|[^'])*?'))
```

It handles Biffens C++11's raw string literal (as well as C# verbatim strings) and it's changed according to Wiktors suggestions.

Split it to handling single and double quotes separately because of difference in logic (and avoiding the non-working back reference ;).

It's undoubtedly more complex, but still far from the solutions I've seen out there which hardly cover any of the *string issues*. And it could be stripped of parts not applicable to a specific language.

One comment suggested *supporting* more languages. That would make the RE (even more) complex and unmanageable. It should be relatively easy to adapt though.

[Updated regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/qY4xD3/6).

Thanks everyone for the input so far. And keep the suggestions coming.

Regards

**Edit:** Update Raw String - this time I actually read the spec. ;)