# deleting all text except what matches regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have regexp, that should delete comments(ye, it's bad, but for me it works)

```
String regex = (^\/\/.*)|(\s+\/\/.*)|((\/\*)(.|\n)+?(\*\/));
```

this code should delete all commtents

```
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(some text).replaceAll(" ");
```

but how can i make it to delete all EXCEPT regexp?

For example:
if i have string like this:

`/*Comments it's cool*/
public static void foo(){}`

my regexp match comments, but i need to delete what doesn't match, so it will look like:

```
/*Comments it's cool*/
```

Comment: Just concatenate all your matches?

Comment: Oh, come on - match with the regex and append them to the resulting string/buffer/etc. BTW, have you really been happy using `(.|\n)+?`? Use `.*?` at least (with the `(?s)` inline modifier). However, there are much better regexps for multiline comments.

Comment: And `(^\/\/.*)|(\s+\/\/.*)` is the same as `(\s*\/\/.*)`.

Comment: B.t.w. You might want to checkout a query/answer of mine: [How to remove C-style comments from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454069/how-to-remove-c-style-comments-from-code).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can just match what your regex matches, and concatenate the matched texts. It is much easier.

As for the regex that *removes* all but what your original pattern matches, you can use consider capturing your whole pattern with a capturing optional group and use a `.` to match any char after it.

Say, your pattern is `abc`. It matches `abc`. But now, you need to match the opposite, everything that your regex does not match. Use

```
(?s)(abc)?.
```

And replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF2vV5/1).

Some adjustment may be necessary though for newlines. If you do not want to remove newlines, do not use the DOTALL modifier. If you want to use it, replace `.` with `[^\n\r]` in the original pattern. Remember, you will be able to shrink the empty lines with some `(\r?\n|\r){2,}` pattern (and again, `$1` backreference).

So, your regex is

```
String regex = "^\\s*//.*|/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/";
```

where `/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` matches multiline comments, and `^\\s*//.*` matches singleline comments.

To make it remove all but what it matches, use

```
String regex = "(?sm)(^\\s*//[^\r\n]*|/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/)?.";
```

and replace with `$1` backreference. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH8pQ1/2) (based on [ClasG demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454069/how-to-remove-c-style-comments-from-code)). Note I also added a `(?m)` MULTILINE modifier for the `^` to match at the beginning of the line.