# How to match comments but not url? c# regex

Tags: c#, regex, comments

How can I match comments in page source that start in symbols "//" but skip urls that also have "//" like "https://test.test.test/testing"?

My code right now is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\/\/(.*?$)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matchCollection1 = regex.Matches(pageSource);
string allMatches = string.Join(";", from Match match1 in matchCollection1 select match1.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: You can check my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454069/how-to-remove-c-style-comments-from-code).

Comment: When you solve the current issue (say, with `@"(?<!\bhttps?:)//(.*)"`), you will come across another. This is something that requires a dedicated parser.

Comment: do a lookbehind for `http`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add not present of ':' symbol and set multi line option

```
[^:]\/\/(.*?$)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/Z8zz0n/2