# Check javascript text for some block listed keywords from java program

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, string-comparison

I have simple javascript as a text input to my method, I just need to validate this text and make sure that it doesn't contain some of the block listed words (for example **eval**) in it, but at the same, I would like to ignore commented text or text defined as string variables.

I am just using simple regex to achieve this, however I cannot ignore comments and string variables in this approach.

```
  public void isValidJavascript(String source, String blocklistedWord) {
     String pattern = "\\b"+blocklistedWord+"\\b";
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Matcher m=p.matcher(source);
     if(m.find()){
         System.out.println("Invalid javascript");
     }
    }
```

Sample Javascript, let's assume my block listed keyword is **import** for this example, so I want contains method to return false for this, because the regex should ignore import in commented line as well as in variable str.

```
//there is import keyword in below string variable
var str = "Apple, Banana, Kiwi, import";
var res = str.slice(7,13);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: *however I cannot ignore comments and string variables in this approach.* Not only comments, but eval can also feature in a string value as well. Instead, use esprima package to highlight the keyword http://esprima.org/demo/highlight.html

Comment: I cannot afford to use a library, it is an existing project where I need to achieve it with simple java technique, the eval is just one example, the block listed word can be anything else like <script or http://....etc

Comment: There are just too many scenario's too consider. Regex is designed for pattern recognition, not to check the syntax of a language which is not a regular language. Can you specify what exactly is missing from your code which you want to handle?

Comment: I just want to check if some specific words exist in a javascript content by ignoring commented lines and string values using some regex pattern.

Comment: Can you share some sample strings (code) to try on?

Comment: Edited my question with sample javascript where I expect the contains method to return false when I pass import as block listed keyword to it.

Comment: Check this QnA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36455937/2064981 It illustrates a way to considers both comments and strings.