# Remove Comments from All Files in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Working on a legacy code base, where lot of inline comments make it difficult to review. Was wondering if there is any extension out there paid / free to remove comments from entire solution.

> Even Resharper does not seem to have this feature, any other extension?

With all my searches, these are the best I could find. But works only within file.
[1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KishoreKumarPattabiraman.CommentsRemoverVsix)
[2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommentRemover)

Comment: "Strange, that even Resharper does not seem to have this feature" - up to this day I could never imagine someone would need such a "feature".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36454069/2064981

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Visual Studio build in replacement (<kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>) with an activate regex search.

[image: Visual Studio RegEx Replace]

As already shown in the image, use `\/\/.*\n` as expression and *nothing* as replacement. But as [@AakashM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71059/aakashm) pointed out in the comments below: You have to be careful, because this regex also matches strings containing `//`.

If your inline comments are just single lines with `/* some comment */` you can use `\/\*.*\*\/`.

And for matching single and multiline comments `/* */` you can use `\/\*(.*?\n?)*\*\/`.

---

*Hint: I tried more complex regex, but this causes visual studio to consume 100% CPU and getting non-responding.*

Comment: @MartinBackasch Thanks for attempting, regex does not search inline comments

Comment: @Abhijeet: I am using Visual Studio 2015 and for me it is working. Make sure you have checked the regex search. Can you show an example of a non working line. May you have to remove the `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommentRemover) plugin if you're running a compatible version of Visual Studio